# Could not set value dynamically into drop down list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to set value dynamically into drop down list using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Business Name :</span>
    <select class="form-control" id="restau" ng-model="subcat" ng-options="qua.name for qua in listOfRestaurant | orderBy:'name' track by qua.value" ng-change="getDayFromSpecial('restau');">
      <option value="">Select Business Name</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Open" ng-click="openGallery();">
   <input type="button" id="btn1" value="select" ng-click="openSelect();">
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
$scope.openSelect=function(){
     $scope.subcat.value="1";
   }
```

Here I am trying to set value using button click but it's throwing error. [Here is my plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NxyFTFBNMJ6qUONs2d0s?p=preview) code.

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't define `$scope.subcat` object yet & you're trying to assign value property of it.

```
$scope.subcat = {}; //define it inside controller
$scope.openSelect=function(){
   $scope.subcat.value = "1";
}
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KXSp5wYpfwvfqY5xzrDy?p=preview)

> **Warning:** as you're only setting `value` property of object, `ng-options` would select option for you in dropdown. But what about other `property` values.
>   If you are assuming `value` as unique constraint & totally responsible
>   entire record identity then its completely fine.

Comment: @ Pankaj : Here is one problem i could not get the set of data in console while click on open button.

Comment: @satya so you have to set whole object to `$scope.subcat` inspite of just value